# Mounting wrecks an old boot drive?

Tags: boot

Got a new SSD drive so disconnected the old HDD and installed 22.04 on the SSD.  Everything went fine.  Re-connected the HDD and mounted it so I could copy off some files.  Still fine.  Then I needed to run a program on the HDD so rebooted and attempted to boot from the HDD but grub came up with a message that there was no OS on the drive.

From BIOS I should be able to chose either drive, right?  Any chance of recovery?

EDIT: I should have mentioned - the HDD had 22.04 on it that had been upgraded from about 17.x each time a new release came.  It booted just fine before installing the new drive, and let me repeat that the HDD was disconnected while I did the SSD install, specifically so nothing would happen to it.  After the SSD installed and loaded with 22.04, then I reattached the HDD and mounted it on a dir in HOME.  So I am very puzzled why BIOS no longer sees it as a bootable drive

Comment: Are both installs UEFI? Grub menu should then offer to boot HDD install? `sudo update-grub`. Although newest versions may have turned os-prober off. You either temporarily turn it on, or manually add boot stanza to 40_custom. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred - I did an edit to the original post.  Does that shed better light on my problem?  If not, can you be more specific on what to do in grub?  I'm not familiar

Comment: Please post link to Boot-Repair Summary report. That gives details so we can explain better what to do. Otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: @oldfred - sorry, I got called out of town, I'll supply the data when I return